# php youtube video download

Tags: php, youtube

I use below script to download youtube video, it works fine in xamp in localhost, but when i put it in my live wev server its not working , I get this code from https://github.com/jeckman/YouTube-Downloader/blob/master/getvideo.php

```
  <?php
    // YouTube Downloader PHP
    // based on youtube-dl in Python http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/
    // by Ricardo Garcia Gonzalez and others (details at url above)
    //
    // Takes a VideoID and outputs a list of formats in which the video can be
    // downloaded

    include_once('curl.php');

    if(isset($_REQUEST['videoid'])) {
        $my_id = $_REQUEST['videoid'];
    } else {
        echo '<p>No video id passed in</p>';
        exit;
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['type'])) {
        $my_type =  $_REQUEST['type'];
    } else {
        $my_type = 'redirect';
    }

    if(isset($_REQUEST['debug'])) {
        $debug = TRUE;
    } else {
        $debug = FALSE;
    }

    if ($my_type == 'Download') {
    ?>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Youtube Downloader</title>
        <meta name="keywords" content="Video downloader, download youtube, video download, youtube video, youtube downloader, download youtube FLV, download youtube MP4, download youtube 3GP, php video downloader" />
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
         <style type="text/css">
          body {
            padding-top: 40px;
            padding-bottom: 40px;
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
        }

          .download {
            max-width: 300px;
            padding: 19px 29px 29px;
            margin: 0 auto 20px;
            background-color: #fff;
            border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
            -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
               -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                    border-radius: 5px;
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
               -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
                    box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
          }

          .download .download-heading {
            margin-bottom: 10px;
          }

          .mime, .itag {
            width: 75px;
            display: inline-block;
          }

          .itag {
            width: 15px;
          }

          .userscript {
            float: right;
            margin-top: 5px
          }
        </style>
        </head>
    <body>
        <div class="download">
        <h1 class="download-heading">Youtube Downloader Results</h1>
    <?php
    } // end of if for type=Download

    /* First get the video info page for this video id */
    $my_video_info = 'http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?&video_id='. $my_id;
    $my_video_info = curlGet($my_video_info);

    /* TODO: Check return from curl for status code */

    parse_str($my_video_info);
    echo '<p><img src="'. $thumbnail_url .'" border="0" hspace="2" vspace="2"></p>';
    $my_title = $title;

    if(isset($url_encoded_fmt_stream_map)) {
        /* Now get the url_encoded_fmt_stream_map, and explode on comma */
        $my_formats_array = explode(',',$url_encoded_fmt_stream_map);
        //if($debug) {
        //  echo '<pre>';
        //  print_r($my_formats_array);
        //  echo '</pre>';
        //}
    } else {
        echo '<p>No encoded format stream found.</p>';
        echo '<p>Here is what we got from YouTube:</p>';
        echo $my_video_info;
    }
    if (count($my_formats_array) == 0) {
        echo '<p>No format stream map found - was the video id correct?</p>';
        exit;
    }

    /* create an array of available download formats */
    $avail_formats[] = '';
    $i = 0;

    foreach($my_formats_array as $format) {
        parse_str($format);
        $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] = $itag;
        $avail_formats[$i]['quality'] = $quality;
        $type = explode(';',$type);
        $avail_formats[$i]['type'] = $type[0];
        $avail_formats[$i]['url'] = urldecode($url) . '&signature=' . $sig;
        parse_str(urldecode($url));
        $avail_formats[$i]['expires'] = date("G:i:s T", $expire);
        $avail_formats[$i]['ipbits'] = $ipbits;
        $avail_formats[$i]['ip'] = $ip;
        $i++;
    }

    if ($debug) {
        echo '<p>These links will expire at '. $avail_formats[0]['expires'] .'</p>';
        echo '<p>The server was at IP address '. $avail_formats[0]['ip'] .' which is an '. $avail_formats[0]['ipbits'] .' bit IP address. ';
        echo 'Note that when 8 bit IP addresses are used, the download links may fail.</p>';
    }
    if ($my_type == 'Download') {
        echo '<ul>
                List of available formats for download:<br>
                <small>Right-click and choose "save as" or click "download" to use this server as proxy.</small>
            </ul>';

        /* now that we have the array, print the options */
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($avail_formats); $i++) {
            echo '<li>' .
                    '<span class="itag">' . $avail_formats[$i]['itag'] . '</span> '.
                    '<a href="' . $avail_formats[$i]['url'] . '" class="mime">' . $avail_formats[$i]['type'] . '</a> ' .
                    '<small>(' .  $avail_formats[$i]['quality'] . ' / ' .
                    '<a href="download.php?mime=' . $avail_formats[$i]['type'] .'&title='. urlencode($my_title) .'&token=' . base64_encode($avail_formats[$i]['url']) . '" class="dl">download</a>' .
                    ')</small></li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    ?>

    <!-- @TODO: Prepend the base URI -->
    <a href="ytdl.user.js" class="userscript btn btn-mini" title="Install chrome extension to view a 'Download' link to this application on Youtube video pages.">
      Install Chrome Extension
    </a>

    </body>
    </html>

    <?php

    } else {

    /* In this else, the request didn't come from a form but from something else
     * like an RSS feed.
     * As a result, we just want to return the best format, which depends on what
     * the user provided in the url.
     * If they provided "format=best" we just use the largest.
     * If they provided "format=free" we provide the best non-flash version
     * If they provided "format=ipad" we pull the best MP4 version
     *
     * Thanks to the python based youtube-dl for info on the formats
     *                              http://rg3.github.com/youtube-dl/
     */

    $format =  $_REQUEST['format'];
    $target_formats = '';
    switch ($format) {
        case "best":
            /* largest formats first */
            $target_formats = array('38', '37', '46', '22', '45', '35', '44', '34', '18', '43', '6', '5', '17', '13');
            break;
        case "free":
            /* Here we include WebM but prefer it over FLV */
            $target_formats = array('38', '46', '37', '45', '22', '44', '35', '43', '34', '18', '6', '5', '17', '13');
            break;
        case "ipad":
            /* here we leave out WebM video and FLV - looking for MP4 */
            $target_formats = array('37','22','18','17');
            break;
        default:
            /* If they passed in a number use it */
            if (is_numeric($format)) {
                $target_formats[] = $format;
            } else {
                $target_formats = array('38', '37', '46', '22', '45', '35', '44', '34', '18', '43', '6', '5', '17', '13');
            }
        break;
    }

    /* Now we need to find our best format in the list of available formats */
    $best_format = '';
    for ($i=0; $i < count($target_formats); $i++) {
        for ($j=0; $j < count ($avail_formats); $j++) {
            if($target_formats[$i] == $avail_formats[$j]['itag']) {
                //echo '<p>Target format found, it is '. $avail_formats[$j]['itag'] .'</p>';
                $best_format = $j;
                break 2;
            }
        }
    }

    //echo '<p>Out of loop, best_format is '. $best_format .'</p>';
    $redirect_url = $avail_formats[$best_format]['url'];
    $content_type = $avail_formats[$best_format]['type'];
    header("Location: $redirect_url");
    } // end of else for type not being Download
    ?>
```

Comment: Check whether CURL php extension is enabled on your hosting or not? Also enable PHP errors so you can see precise error messages.

Comment: you have given us so little to go on

Comment: @JayBhatt, curl php extension is enabled, i cant see the error because it showing content of index.php instead of of download.php, which was okey in localhost 
Dagon, please check the github link, i fully installed it, worked in only local host

Comment: So it is running the wrong script?

Comment: try this:  https://weibomiaopai.com/download-video-parser.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try opening a port on your router which redirects to your computer's local host. Your ISP is probably blocking port 80 so change your broadcast port to 8080 for Apache. Try accessing your computer externally through the internet and downloading a youtube video. If this does not give you an issue, than your web host might be blocking it.

I tried it on my web host, and it worked fine, are you getting any errors?

Comment: solved it, problem was ip, used a proxy and worked fine

Comment: @kishordgupta.lilait.com how did you used proxy, im also facing the same issue