# How to get youtube download link from this array

Tags: php, arrays, url, youtube, download

I have a PHP script that returns the youtube's **url_encoded_fmt_stream_map** into arrays

this is an example of one of those arrays

```
Array
(
[quality] => hd720
[itag] => 45
[url] => http://r7---sn-25ge7n7l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&expire=1377205488&cp=U0hWTFJLU19NUkNONl9KRVdFOlFROHcyQXZRVzMw&sver=3&mt=1377182899&itag=45&id=f3a24c732e4ea990&upn=aBSr1FoD9WM&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=919112%2C919363%2C914074%2C916624%2C909546%2C906397%2C929117%2C929121%2C929906%2C929907%2C929922%2C929127%2C929129%2C929131%2C929930%2C925720%2C925722%2C925718%2C929917%2C929919%2C929933%2C912521%2C919206%2C932306%2C913428%2C920605%2C904830%2C919373%2C930803%2C908536%2C904122%2C938701%2C911423%2C936308%2C909549%2C900816%2C912711%2C904494%2C904497%2C900375%2C906001&ipbits=8&ratebypass=yes&ip=31.170.160.74&key=yt1&ms=au&mv=u
[fallback_host] => tc.v23.cache8.c.youtube.com
[type] => video/webm; codecs=\"vp8.0, vorbis\"
[sig] => 1A6118D09B20DCD2CD068CAD2415C6BFF80FF5F0.5FB3424173B8FABE7379689138DFA7038B5F11B4
)
```

how can i put these informations together to make a valid download link ?

any help will be much appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: Its not that simple.
Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626992/php-youtube-video-download

Answer (score 0):

The download url is already there in the result, for example :

`http://r7---sn-25ge7n7l.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?source=youtube&expire=1377205488&cp=U0hWTFJLU19NUkNONl9KRVdFOlFROHcyQXZRVzMw&sver=3&mt=1377182899&itag=45&id=f3a24c732e4ea990&upn=aBSr1FoD9WM&sparams=cp%2Cid%2Cip%2Cipbits%2Citag%2Cratebypass%2Csource%2Cupn%2Cexpire&fexp=919112%2C919363%2C914074%2C916624%2C909546%2C906397%2C929117%2C929121%2C929906%2C929907%2C929922%2C929127%2C929129%2C929131%2C929930%2C925720%2C925722%2C925718%2C929917%2C929919%2C929933%2C912521%2C919206%2C932306%2C913428%2C920605%2C904830%2C919373%2C930803%2C908536%2C904122%2C938701%2C911423%2C936308%2C909549%2C900816%2C912711%2C904494%2C904497%2C900375%2C906001&ipbits=8&ratebypass=yes&ip=31.170.160.74&key=yt1&ms=au&mv=u`

will be the url you are looking for in above. This url will change with every request and also only available from the IP which requested it.